# Ack plugin inside the vim is not working

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, ack

I'm getting following error inside `vim` while using `Ack` plugin:

`[ No Name]`
`|| ack-grep: Command not found.`

I have installed `ack` vim-plugin at the path `~/.vim/bundle/ack.vim`. I have checked with `:scriptnames`, it shows me proper path.

Added following entries to my `.vimrc` file:

```
let g:ackprg="ack-grep -H --nocolor --nogroup --column"
nmap <leader>a <Esc>:Ack!
```

I'm still getting the error. Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the error is `ack-grep: Command not found` the vim can’t find the `ack-grep` command. So it’s not be a problem with the plugin, but instead a problem in your (shell) environment.

Run `which ack-grep` from the shell and make sure you actually do have an `ack-grep` that’s executable and that’s in your `$PATH` so that vim can find it.

Answer (score 5):

One of the requirements for running the Plugin is to have Ack >= 2.0 installed on your machine.

For Ubuntu/Debian this should work:

```
sudo apt-get install ack-grep
```

Here are installation steps for other OS http://beyondgrep.com/install/